# How to get Media Volume in Ionic 3?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I need to get a current media volume in Ionic 3 app because I want to continue to next step of app flow when phone media volume is at least 80%.
Does anybody have some kind of possible solution?

Answer (score 0):

Hey  You Can Have 2 Strategies

1. To Set  Media Volume to 80% for Which You Can Use CordovaMedia Plugin if the  Scenario You  are Facing Deals with  Media Files. 
   In this Case You Could  Use : https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-media
   this Plugin .
   You  Can Use Set Volume Method for This purpose .
   media.setVolume: Set the volume for audio playback.
2. In This Scenario You Need to Set the Phone Volume 
   you Can Use this https://github.com/mgcrea/cordova-plugin-volume-control Plugin in Case  to **Get** and **Set** the Volume.

   > VolumeControl.getVolume(console.log.bind(console));
   >
   > VolumeControl.setVolume(0.15);